# How do I bind an variable to be the value of my html input in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with a method post, but I have to encrypt some of the parameters to md5 before I post them in my javascript. How do I bind the values to that form.

html form:

```
<input id="sig"  name="signature" >signature <i class="fa fa-usd" aria-hidden="true">
</i></br>
```

javascript:

```
vm.sig_md5 = $.md5('value');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery `.submit()` to modify the value at the time of form submission *(value is modified before submit, then submit continues).*

**HTML:**

```
<form action="somewhere.php" method="post">
    <input id="sig"  name="signature" >signature <i class="fa fa-usd" aria-hidden="true"></i></br>
</form>
```

**jQuery/javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(){
        var sig = $('#sig').val();
        sig_md5 = $.md5(sig);
        $('#sig').val(sig_md5);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use getter if you don't care about IE<=9

```
var data = {}
Object.defineProperty(data, 'signature', { 
   get: function() { return document.getElementById('sig').value; },
   set: function(value) { /* set input value hereif needed */ }
})
```

[read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) on MDN

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript:

```
<input id="sig"  name="signature" >signature <i class="fa fa-usd" aria-hidden="true">

<script>

    var vm = {};
    document.getElementById("sig").addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
        vm.sig_md5 = event.target.value; console.log(vm.sig_md5);
    });

</script>
```

You can simply attach a keyup event listener and set your variable to it's value.

Comment: Thanks I'll try it out. But what if "signature" is a hidden value, do I still include the event listener?

Comment: or do I use .bind?

Comment: I'm not sure about whether it's hidden.. but I'm sure `.bind` would work just as well, I tested it in jsFiddle so I used javascript, but you don't have to.